# How can I limit CloudFront downloads

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm looking to use Amazon's CloudFront to host some content in the near future. Currently, I'm keeping it very simple and I'm just uploading my content to S3 and then making a distribution available via Cloudfront.

However, because I have a limited budget, I'd like to be able to limit the number of downloads or the money spent on bandwidth. As far as I can see, I can't set any quotas or budgets like you can in Google's App Engine, so I'm looking for another way of doing this.

Has anyone had any experience doing this? One approach I'm thinking of is having to place a webserver with redirects in between, but that kind of defeats the simplicity of CF for me.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there are no quotas or budgets built-in to CloudFront either. However, you can create [private, dynamic signed URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) that will limit access to your distribution. So, you can distribute unique URLs from your site with short lifetimes and when you reach your budget, stop. This is not the intended usage for CloudFront Private Content, but I think it might meet your need.